# What is the template file name for a bean block?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

My block is called "hero", on the front-end the class is `block-bean-hero`, what is the proper template file name for this block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can infer from the class name, your module name is "bean", so the template name should be `block--bean--hero.tpl.php`. For more information you can check the [Template (theme hook) suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions) documentation.